# Can I travel with a TV as luggage?

Tags: usa, luggage, colombia

I want to buy a TV in the US because here (Colombia) TVs are more expensive.

Will I have any problem with this? Will the airline allow me to send a TV as luggage? Will the airline pay me if they break the TV?

Comment: Please check if the potential duplicate linked to in the comment above already answers your question. Otherwise please point out in which points your question is different and what is not answer by the other post. Also please specify the rough dimensions of the TV you wish to import, its approximate cost (for import duties) and which airline you wish to fly, otherwise your question risks being unclear / too broad.

Comment: With most airlines, yes.  But the baggage handlers will likely break it.

Comment: The duplicate answers the packing and breakage question; the duty calculation will vary by country. In this digital age, there's no problem with incompatible video systems?